# Web server and android phone communication by JSON

Tags: php, android, json, apache, http

I have some trouble in creating a connection using PHP script on the web server and android phone by POST with JSON inside. The server receive the connection, but it don't see my JSON array (or any content inside POST).

I tried many methods to send POST from android but I always have this error  **"Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"** and user not found, because I have no data to enter in for each. But I have correct JSON in Android.
Is there some issue with sending data on server or decoding data in PHP script?

I have a trouble in android or with PHP script? Also, how can I fix it?

I have HttpClient class, for connecting for server:

```
public class HttpClient {
private static final String TAG = "HttpClient";

public static JSONObject SendHttpPost(String URL, JSONObject jsonObjSend) {

    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPostRequest = new HttpPost(URL);

        StringEntity se;
        se = new StringEntity("jsonData="+jsonObjSend.toString());
        Log.i("Json: ",jsonObjSend.toString());
        Log.v("Entity: ",se.toString());

        httpPostRequest.setEntity(se);
        httpPostRequest.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPostRequest.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        httpPostRequest.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");

        long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Log.d("Send: ",httpPostRequest.toString());
        HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpPostRequest);
        Log.i(TAG, "HTTPResponse received in [" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - t) + "ms]");

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        if (entity != null) {
            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
            Header contentEncoding = response.getFirstHeader("Content-Encoding");
            if (contentEncoding != null && contentEncoding.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")) {
                instream = new GZIPInputStream(instream);
            }

            String resultString= convertStreamToString(instream);
            instream.close();
            resultString = resultString.substring(0,resultString.length()-1);

            JSONObject jsonObjRecv = new JSONObject(resultString);
            Log.i(TAG, "<JSONObject>\n" + jsonObjRecv.toString() + "\n</JSONObject>");

            return jsonObjRecv;
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
            Log.e("JSON", "" + line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}}
```

This is my JSON Array generation and SendHttpPost method calling:

```
 public void onLoginClick(View view) throws Exception{

    TextView mlogin=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.loginText);
    TextView mpass=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordText);
    String inputLogin=mlogin.getText().toString();
    String inputpass=mpass.getText().toString();
    asincWork loginPost = new asincWork();
    String[] params;
    params=new String[2];
    params[0]=inputLogin;
    params[1]=inputpass;
    loginPost.doInBackground(params);

}

private class asincWork extends AsyncTask{
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
        super.onPostExecute(o);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Object[] params) {
        com.example.fluffysith.myapplication.HttpClient httpClient=new com.example.fluffysith.myapplication.HttpClient();
        String error_msg = "Server error!";  JSONObject response;
        try {
            JSONObject mJsonObject = new JSONObject();
            mJsonObject.put("loginEmail", params[0]);
            mJsonObject.put("loginPass", params[1]);
            String URL="http://zachotka.co.nf/query/getProfileInfo.php?pass";

            //Log.e("Send Obj:", mJsonObject.toString());
            response = httpClient.SendHttpPost(URL, mJsonObject);
            boolean status = response != null && response.getInt("is_error") == 0; // response

            return status;
        } catch (JSONException | NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
           // mDialog.dismiss();
            return false;
        }
    }

}
    protected void onPreExecute() {
       // super.onPreExecute();
    }
```

And php script on the server:

```
 <?php
$file = 'getProfileInfolog.txt';
$current = file_get_contents($file);

$current .='
'. date("d.m.y H:i:s").'  |  ';

include('../db.php');
if(isset($_GET['pass']))// ЕСЛИ ЗАПРАШИВАЕТСЯ только сравнить пароли
{
    //$data = json_decode($_POST['jsonData']);

    $data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['jsonData']));

    $current .= "data = "+$data;
    file_put_contents($file, $current);

    foreach ($data as $key=>$value) 
    {
        $userInfo[$key]=$value;
    }
    $userPass= hash('sha256', $userInfo['loginPass']);

    $current .= "Pass
    ";

    $userEmail = $userInfo['loginEmail'];

        $current.= "email = ".$userInfo['loginEmail'];
        $current.= " 
                    pass = ".$userInfo['loginPass'];
        $current.= " 
                    pass = ".$userPass;

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT  pass  FROM users WHERE email = '$userEmail'", $db);
    $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        if ($myrow)//если есть такой пользователь
            {
                $current .= "

                ".$myrow['pass']."
                ".$userPass;

                if ($myrow['pass']==$userPass)//сравниваем паролли
                    {
                        echo 'OK';//если все правильно

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo 'passNotTrue'; //если все правильно
                    }

            }
            else
            {
            echo 'userNotFound';    //пользователя не существует
            }
}
else // ЕСЛИ ЗАПРАШИВАЕТСЯ ВСЯ ИНФА
{
    if(isset($_GET['userInfo']))
    {
        $data = json_decode($_POST['jsonData']);
            foreach ($data as $key=>$value) {
                $userInfo[$key]=$value;
                }

        $email = $userInfo['loginEmail'];

                                $current.="ALL inf
                                email = ". $email."
                                ";

        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'", $db);

    $myRow = mysql_fetch_array($result);

echo json_encode($myRow);
$current.= $myRow;
    }
}

$current .=  mysql_error();

//file_put_contents($file, $current);
?>
```

Comment: Using `Retrofit`/`gson` will make this a lot easier.

Comment: is the foreach error in android or through http?

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly true that. Use any of the libraries like Retrofit or Volley or OkHttp. That will make things easier for you. You will be able to clean your code, keep them manageable and you will get a clear idea of what data you are sending and what is being received by the app.

Comment: i try to use gson, but it dont fix my problem, i know it easier...i hope a difficult way can give me a result:)

Comment: @Suraj Rao in php script.

Comment: @Suraj Rao there:

$data = json_decode($_POST['jsonData']);
            foreach ($data as $key=>$value) {
                $userInfo[$key]=$value;
                }

Comment: Also.. you are checking if(isset($_GET['pass'])) but i dont see any value set for pass parameter in the url..

Comment: it my partner's script. I ask him to check it.
He said it read from getProfileInfolog.txt ( but he dont use this data, i don't understand why he did it:D )  but we dont read post data from log.
Post data read's by $post = file_get_contents('php://input').

Comment: `String URL="http://zachotka.co.nf/query/getProfileInfo.php?pass";`
there, in java i write pass in URL.

Comment: isset($_GET['pass']) will check if pass has value  for example: http://zachotka.co.nf/query/getProfileInfo.php?pass=1

Comment: I try to put value there - no changes. Still exception in foreach...

Comment: @Suraj Rao i try many methods in android - always this mistake. I think it in php problem.

Comment: instead         httpPostRequest.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
 try application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: Oh my God, it works!!
I have only "user not found" now, but it major problem.
Thank you so much;))

Comment: ok..I will add an answer why it worked :P

Comment: @МаксимРайлян try echo data variable and check if you are retrieving values correctly.

Comment: Allthing okey, thank you, you save us student project))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you were not getting data from _POST[].

Your content type in android is 'application/json'
Even though you were creating json object here -

```
JSONObject mJsonObject = new JSONObject();
            mJsonObject.put("loginEmail", params[0]);
            mJsonObject.put("loginPass", params[1]);
```

You were setting it as a key - value pair

```
se = new StringEntity("jsonData="+jsonObjSend.toString());
```

making it a form with key jsonData and value as json encoded object.

You need to redo the setting of the request body or set:

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```